# Ant Custom Tree Select is closing dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, antd

I'm having an issue when I try to implement a right-click inside of the tree nodes you can checkout my example in the link, the problem is basically that every time I try to click on the menu Items, my Select Dropdown gets close, please somebody Help me!

https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-dropdown-antd4152-forked-4lv9p?file=/index.js

[Small Sample video GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJfe4.gif)

Comment: Did you try to use `getPopupContainer` for your inner dropdown? I'm not sure that it can help you, but probably it is a right direction of solution

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the getPopupContainer didn't work, however, thanks for the collaboration @raman